# Cursor index out of bounds exception that is passing null check

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I checked a bunch of questions here and I cannot find correct answer. I have problem with retrieving data from my database. I get `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0` exception. My code for creating database:

```
   String KREIRAJ_TABELU = "CREATE TABLE " + IME_TABELE + "("
    + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + PITANJE + " TEXT,"
    + PRVI_NETACAN + " TEXT," + DRUGI_NETACAN + " TEXT," + TRECI_NETACAN + " TEXT," + TACAN_ODGOVOR + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(KREIRAJ_TABELU);
    String dodajPitanjaIOdgovore = "INSERT INTO pitanja (ID,PITANJE,PRVI_NETACAN,DRUGI_NETACAN,TRECI_NETACAN,TACAN_ODGOVOR)\n" +
            "VALUES (0,\"Ovo je prvo pitanje:\",\"Netacan odgovor\",\"Netacan odgovor\",\"Netacan odgovor\",\"Tacan odgovor\");\n" +
            "\n" + ...
db.execSQL(dodajPitanjaIOdgovore);
```

And for retriving data I use this piece of code:

```
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(IME_TABELE, new String[]{ID,
            PITANJE, PRVI_NETACAN, DRUGI_NETACAN, TRECI_NETACAN, TACAN_ODGOVOR}, ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    podaciOPitanjima podaci = new podaciOPitanjima(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
    return podaci;
```

Edit: I also tried this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    podaciOPitanjima podaci = new podaciOPitanjima(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
}
else{
    podaciOPitanjima podaci;
}
podaciOPitanjima podaci = new podaciOPitanjima(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));
return podaci;
```

Comment: Try with try catch block..

Comment: `if(cursor.getCount() > 0)` what do you think happens if this condition is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
}
//do operations here
```

To

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    //do operations here
}
```

*Explanation - the problem is this line:*

```
podaci = new poda...ima(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), ...);
```

When you use `cursor.getString` the cursor is not actually at a row (because there is no row), so you cannot get a *cell/column* which is what this command is asking for.

***The full solution:***

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(IME_TABELE, new String[]{ID, PITANJE, PRVI_NETACAN, DRUGI_NETACAN, TRECI_NETACAN, TACAN_ODGOVOR}, ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
podaciOPitanjima podaci = null;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    //Note: using getColumnIndex avoids errors if the columns are ever returned in a changed order
    podaci = new podaciOPitanjima(
         cursor.getInteger( cursor.getColumnIndex(ID) ), 
         cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(PITANJE) ), 
         cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(PRVI_NETACAN) ), 
         cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(DRUGI_NETACAN) ), 
         cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(TRECI_NETACAN) ), 
         cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex(TACAN_ODGOVOR) ));
}
return podaci;
```

Now remember wherever you are calling this method, that you might get `null` back and that you need to check for that.

Comment: I edited my post with code I tried and it still don't work. I just get Index 0 requested instead -1

Comment: @Slay29 your edit is still incorrect, you still access the cursor if there is nothing in it. if `cursor.moveToFirst()` is false you should return `null` or something because there is nothing in the cursor. if `cursor.moveToFirst()` is true then return `podaci`

Comment: Oh, I see your point! Nice! Thank you very much! I feel kinda stupid in the moment because I didn't thought this through enough! Thank you one more time!